# Issue in passing data in zipkin via kafka - Could not convert message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, zipkin

```
2020-01-10 15:21:24.988  INFO [tracing-zipkin-server,,,] 13752 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Setting newly assigned partitions [sleuth-0] for group sleuth
2020-01-10 15:21:24.997  INFO [tracing-zipkin-server,,,] 13752 --- [           -C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$3  : partitions assigned:[sleuth-0]
2020-01-10 15:21:25.032 ERROR [tracing-zipkin-server,,,] 13752 --- [           -L-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder 
: Could not convert message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java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 454
    at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.oldExtractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:154) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.EmbeddedHeaderUtils.extractHeaders(EmbeddedHeaderUtils.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$ReceivingHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:546) ~[spring-cloud-stream-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:70) [spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.FixedSubscriberChannel.send(FixedSubscriberChannel.java:64) [spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) [spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) [spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) [spring-messaging-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188) [spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$200(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:63) [spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:372) [spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:352) [spring-integration-kafka-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter$1.doWithRetry(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) [spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180) [spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:73) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingAcknowledgingMessageListenerAdapter.java:39) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:792) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2100(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:246) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1025) [spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>tracing-zipkin-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin.stream.EnableZipkinStreamServer;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinStreamServer
public class ZipkinServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to solve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far to solve your problem? Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Sometimes, this helps to find the problem by yourself.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of spring? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent